# I'm getting the strange output from in_array function

Tags: php, arrays

in php the following code returns `true`

```
$array = array(
  'isReady' => false,
  'isPHP' => true,
  'isStrange' => true
);
var_dump(in_array('sitepoint.com', $array));
```

result is a `true` WHY ?

Comment: because: `('sitepoint.com' == true) === true`

Comment: they are not same questions @Thomas Andrews

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the 3rd parameter to [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array), `$strict`.

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

By default it's `FALSE`, which makes it use `==`.

```
'sitepoint.com' == true
```

That's actually true (because of PHP's type juggling)!

You want to do:

```
in_array('sitepoint.com', $array, TRUE);
```

That will make it use `===`.

```
'sitepoint.com' === true
```

That's not true.

Comment: Why 'sitepoint.com' == true is true ? I confused :)

Comment: @Anri: Because what PHP is doing when you do `in_array` is loop over the array and compare your passed value to the values in the array.  When it gets to `true`, it does `'sitepoint.com' == true`.  These 2 types are not the same, so it needs to convert them.  You are comparing a string to a boolean, so it converts the string to a boolean so that they are the same types.  In the docs, it explains how this works (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).  So `'sitepoint.com' == true` becomes `(bool)'sitepoint.com' == true` which is `true == true`.

Comment: thank you @Rocket Hazmat for good explenation

Answer (score 3):

`in_array` performs loose comparison (value checking only, not type & value). Since your array values are all booleans (`true` and `false`), the search string (*"sitepoint.com"*) is being coerced to a boolean, effectively, your code translates to:

```
var_dump(in_array((bool)'sitepoint.com', array(true, false, true)));
```

Since a string, when cast to `bool` is `true`, `in_array` returns `true`.
To force type and value checking, pass `true` as third argument to `in_array`.

[cf the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)